# Structure of lead(II,IV) oxide

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, molecular-structure, crystallography

I need help sorting out the molecular structure of [tri-lead tetroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II,IV)_oxide), aka lead(II,IV) oxide $\ce{Pb3O4}$.

This [data sheet](http://www.labsupply.co.za/chemicals/t-z/tri-lead%20tetroxide.PDF) shows this image:

[image]

The Wikipedia's [lead (II,IV) oxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II,IV)_oxide)'s link to a [Jmol interactive image](http://chemapps.stolaf.edu/jmol/jmol.php?model=O1%5BPb%5DO%5BPb%5D11O%5BPb%5DO1) looks like this:

[image]

Even the Wikipedia article's [Talk Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Lead(II,IV)_oxide)'s discussion on the naming and structure makes for interesting reading.

The first drawing shows a $\ce{Pb-O-Pb-O-Pb-O -}$ ring, the second shows a 4-bond $\ce{Pb}$ in the middle with two 2-bond $\ce{Pb}$'s on either side.

Is there a "right way" and a "wrong way" to draw a single molecule of $\ce{Pb3O4}$ that represents how it might actually be configured? Are both, either, or neither of the above representations "right"?

Comment: It's not a molecule, it's an extended solid. Drawing this is as wrong as drawing a covalently bound molecule of NaCl. For the structure of Pb3O4 see e.g. Wells *Structural Inorganic Chemistry* 5ed, p 558

Comment: @orthocresol Isn't there some fundamental concept in Chemistry - the solid can be subdivided to individual molecules? At some point can not a single molecule exist? Would it not be stable? If it can not exist, that would be the basis of an answer.

Comment: If you have access to scientific papers, [this, Fayek, Leciejewi, Zeitsch. f. anorg. u. allg. Chemie, 2004, 336, 104-110](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/zaac.19653360115/pdf) could be worth reading.

Also, what orthocresol said. Its a crystal, painting a molecule is in no case right.

Comment: @Fl.pf. I did not ask about a crystal. I asked about a single molecule. Can that simply not exist? Is that the answer? Or perhaps both might? There are molecular beams that can be neutral, there are inorganic molecules on gold or silicon surfaces in ultra-high vacuum just for example.

Comment: No, a crystal cannot in general be subdivided into individual molecules. I remember a question on this site about it, I will try to search.

Comment: @orthocresol Aren't water and  ice just two examples of distinct water molecules interacting via hydrogen bonds? At least most of them?

Comment: Yes, but ice melts to form water molecules. Pb3O4 doesn't melt to form Pb3O4 molecules. In fact it doesn't even melt, it decomposes (Wikipedia). NaCl doesn't melt to form NaCl molecules, it forms Na+ and Cl- ions. Therefore it would not be correct to think of NaCl solid as an aggregation of NaCl molecules.

Comment: @orthocresol OK let's not get side-tracked by what "in general" means, and I didn't ask about $\ce{ Pb_3O_4 }$ melting, and I could have just as easily said the water sublimated, right? Here, for this question, I would just like to know about a single molecule of $\ce{ Pb_3O_4 }$, and general guidelines of what happens in general are probably not going to help me right now.

Comment: Yes, but even if it sublimates it's still water, with H-O-H covalent bonds. The truth is that Pb-O bonding is not very covalent. As far as I can tell, there is no potential for the formation of discrete Pb3O4 molecules. Maybe it would help if you added some context as to why you're curious about the structure of a single Pb3O4 molecule.

Comment: @orthocresol OK that's something I can definitely understand - thanks! As far as the "why", there isn't a particular context as much as that it seemed to be an opportunity to understand chemistry better. Currently I thought of crystals as either of two extremes - just one giant molecule made of unit cells (e.g silicon) or an ordered array of distinct molecules (e.g. ice - no, not quartz!). So this molecule piqued my interest because it didn't seem to fit nicely with  my "two kinds of crystals" thinking.

Comment: Come to think of it, the very tags "inorganic-chemistry" and "molecular-structure" are inherently contradictory.

Comment: @Fl.pf. ok I've got the paper - neutron diffraction from 1965 - *I love the papers* when each step in the thinking is explained. Great choice!

Comment: @uhoh I'm glad I could be of assistance :)

Comment: @IvanNeretin would you say $\ce{N_2}$ is inorganic? And does it have a molecular structure? ;)

Comment: Yeah, well, all right, let's say "often contradictory".

Comment: @IvanNeretin I've asked a new [molecular-structure question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/72270/16035).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you call a *molecular structure* is in reality an [*asymmetric unit*](http://reference.iucr.org/dictionary/Asymmetric_unit). These two terms are not related, and in general are not interchangeable. The same way $\ce{Pb3O4}$ is not a *molecular formula*, but a [*formula unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_unit).

All pictures you presented are correct in terms that they do represent an asymmetric unit, but actually an [IUCr](http://www.iucr.org/)-recommended asymmetric unit (can be generated with [Olex2](http://www.olexsys.org/)'s command `standardise`) looks like this:

$\color{#FF0D0D}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{O}$;
$\color{#575961}{\Large\bullet}~\ce{Pb}$.

[image]

... and with $Z = 4$ these are packed in a unit cell with [$Pbam$ space group](http://img.chem.ucl.ac.uk/sgp/large/055az1.htm) accordingly:

[image]
[image]

The crystal structure itself can be represented as infinite layers of cross-linked chains made of $\ce{[PbO6]}$ octahedra, which are stacked via $\ce{- O-Pb-O -}$ bridges:

[image]

Crystallographic data is taken from ICSD #9753 [1].

1. Gavarri, J. R.; Weigel, D.; Hewat, A. W. *Journal of Solid State Chemistry* **1978**, 23 (3), 327–339. DOI [10.1016/0022-4596(78)90081-6](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4596(78)90081-6).

Comment: This is very helpful! It's late here and I was just about to log out. I now understand the term *asymmetric unit* and I'm guessing after tomorrow morning's coffee I will understand how to put them together and still get the stoichiometry right, and why the Pb is sometimes drawn with thee bonds to O, and sometimes with four.

Comment: Later than I expected it seems, sorry for the delay and thank you for the clear, concise, and well-sourced answer!